# Using OS X 10.7 Lion: CHUD (Shark & OpenGL Profiler) fail to install correctly

Tags: xcode, macos, profiling, profiler, osx-lion

I've recently installed Lion, then the latest version of XCode available from the Mac App store. (Version 4.1)

I then searched around and discovered that in order to install OpenGL Profiler tools and Shark profiler I needed to install CHUD.

But when I do try to install it, it fails at the end stating that I need to contact the software manufacturer.

I noticed that CHUD was last updated around 2009. Has anyone else experienced such issues?

How do you resolve them?

Thank

Mark

Comment: I get the same error.  Don't have a solution yet though.  I know Instruments is supposed to replace Shark, but unfortunately instruments doesn't seem to have a CPU cache profiler which is what I'm looking for

Comment: I get several errors like this (replace * with names of CHUD kexts) when I try to install CHUD tools in 10.8: "Can't load //System/Library/Extensions/*.kext - no code for running kernel's architecture." Perhaps it's the 64-bit kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Instruments is suppose to replace Shark and OpenGL Profiler comes preinstalled with Xcode.